# Python: loop though list calling functions in namespace

Tags: python, loops, dynamic, dictionary, namespaces

```
# single call to a dict in a namespace
print namespaced.dict1
print namespaced.dict2

# dynamic list of dict names to be used
othernamespace.list = ['dict1', 'dict2']

for element in othernamespace.list:
    # a string of what would be a valid dict
    dynamicDict = 'namespaced.'+element
    print dynamicDict
```

Background info:

In a module I'm reading from an ini file and putting some values (dict titles) into a list. In the main script I then want to loop though that list and print the contents each dict. The dicts were imported from another module.

The first two print statements print the contents of the dict. The following two print statements print the dict names (strings). How can I get them to print the dict contents not the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr)

Comment: `dynamicDict = getattr(namespaced, element)`

Worked like a charm. Thank you.